# How to use InputSimulator to simulate specific keys on Remote Desktop?

Tags: c#, input, simulation, rdp

Im currently using the InputSimulator v0.1.0.0 to simulate keypresses and/or mouse events over Remote Desktop. Basic keypresses (for example pressing 'a') works, but special characters, like 'tab', 'enter' dont.
I simulate entering texts with:

```
InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("blabla");
```

but the following only works locally:

```
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
```

or

```
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
```

I searched over the net for working examples but i havent found anything useful. Anyone has idea how to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

-------------------------OWN ANSWER----------------------------------

After googling some more, i have found this article:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event

in which there is a good code, that does not solve the InputSimulator problem, but does exactly that i need. Here is the code, and how i used that:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct KEYBOARD_INPUT
    {
        public const uint Type = 1;
        public ushort wVk;
        public ushort wScan;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ushort wVk;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public ushort wScan;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public uint dwFlags;
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public uint time;
        [FieldOffset(12)]
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public uint uMsg;
        public ushort wParamL;
        public ushort wParamH;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct INPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int type;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public MOUSEINPUT mi;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public KEYBDINPUT ki;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    };
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, IntPtr pInput, int cbSize);
```

And this is how i called the 'press TAB' event:

```
keybd_event(0x09, 0x0f, 0, 0); // Tab Press

keybd_event(0x09, 0x0f, 0x0002, 0);
```

Comment: It would be better if you could create an actual answer to your question and put your solution there, as it will make your answer more useful to future visitors (as the question will clearly have a working answer).

Comment: In the meanwhile i have completely removed the InputSimulator logic, and im using only keybd_event, thats why im not sure if my solution is a real answer for the question. But i will add my solution as an answer, maybe its better for anyone working for similar problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested i copy my solution as an answer. I hope these will help for anyone working on similar problems. :) The solution is a bit long, but the problem was not only 'how-to-press a button programatically', but also 'how-to-make it work via remote desktop' and 'how-to-make a general solution for different keyboards'. Well, im not 100% sure that the last problem is completely solved, but the solution below may be used for further developing. I also know that the code is not optimal and sometimes ugly, but im still testing and developing it! :)

```
//m_text is the whole text i want to write. It may contain special characters,
//like 'enter', 'tab', lower/upper-case chars, and chars with shit/alt is
//pressed, like ';'.

                //Test with this string, its difficult-enough. :)
                string m_text = "123qweQWE;{tab}!{eNTer}*|";

                IntPtr keyboardLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);

                while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m_text))
                {
                    int m_Index = 0;

                    //Enter, tab and similar keys are in {} brackets
                    //(for example {tab}). We get the 'tab' from the
                    //string and pass this to our method. Key combinations
                    //are separated by a '+' like {alt+tab+tab}, from this
                    //we will get 'press the alt, then press the tab, then
                    //press the tab again'.
                    if (m_text[m_Index] == '{')
                    {
                        #region [ Special chars ]
                        string m_SubString = m_text.Substring(
                                                    m_Index + 1, m_text.IndexOf("}") - 1);

                        string[] m_Splitted = m_SubString.Split(new char[] { '+' });

                        for (int i = 0; i < m_Splitted.Length; i++)
                        {
                            //If the string is longer than 1 char it means we are processing a tab-like key.
                            if (m_Splitted[i].Length > 1)
                                PressSpecial(m_Splitted[i]);
                            else
                            {
                                //If the char is 1-char-long, it means we previously pressed a tab-like key,
                                //and now we press a simple key, like in the case of {altgr+w}.

                                //Get the virtual key of the char.
                                short vKey = VkKeyScanEx(
                                    char.Parse(m_Splitted[i]), keyboardLayout);

                                //Get the low byte from the virtual key.
                                byte m_LOWBYTE = (Byte)(vKey & 0xFF);

                                //Get the scan code of the key.
                                byte sScan = (byte)MapVirtualKey(m_LOWBYTE, 0);

                                //Press the key.
                                //Key down event, as indicated by the 3rd parameter that is 0.
                                keybd_event(m_LOWBYTE, sScan, 0, 0);
                            }
                        }

                        Application.DoEvents();

                        //We have pressed all the keys we wanted, now release them in backward-order
                        //when pressing alt+tab we beed to release them in tab-alt order! The logic is the same.
                        for (int i = m_Splitted.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
                        {
                            if (m_Splitted[i].Length > 1)
                                ReleaseSpecial(m_Splitted[i]);
                            else
                            {
                                short vKey = VkKeyScanEx(
                                    char.Parse(m_Splitted[i]), keyboardLayout);

                                byte m_LOWBYTE = (Byte)(vKey & 0xFF);

                                byte sScan = (byte)MapVirtualKey(m_LOWBYTE, 0);

                                //Key up event, as indicated by the 3rd parameter that is 0x0002.
                                keybd_event(m_LOWBYTE, sScan, 0x0002, 0); //Key up
                            }
                        }

                        Application.DoEvents();

                        #endregion

                        //We do not use the '{' and '}' brackets, thats why the '+2'. :)
                        m_Index = m_SubString.Length + 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        #region [ One char ]
                        short vKey = VkKeyScanEx(m_text[m_Index], keyboardLayout);

                        //Hi-byte indicates if we need to press shift, alt or other similar keys.
                        byte m_HIBYTE = (Byte)(vKey >> 8);
                        byte m_LOWBYTE = (Byte)(vKey & 0xFF);

                        byte sScan = (byte)MapVirtualKey(m_LOWBYTE, 0);

                        //Press the special key if needed.
                        if ((m_HIBYTE == 1))
                            PressShift();
                        else if ((m_HIBYTE == 2))
                            PressControl();
                        else if ((m_HIBYTE == 4))
                            PressAlt();
                        else if ((m_HIBYTE == 6))
                            PressAltGr();

                        //Press, then release the key.
                        keybd_event(m_LOWBYTE, sScan, 0, 0); //Key down
                        keybd_event(m_LOWBYTE, sScan, 0x0002, 0); //Key up

                        //Release the special key if needed.
                        if ((m_HIBYTE == 1))
                            ReleaseShift();
                        else if ((m_HIBYTE == 2))
                            ReleaseControl();
                        else if ((m_HIBYTE == 4))
                            ReleaseAlt();
                        else if ((m_HIBYTE == 6))
                            ReleaseAltGr();
                        #endregion

                        //Get the next char from the string.
                        m_Index++;
                    }

                    //Remove the already processed chars from the string.
                    if (m_Index < m_text.Length)
                        m_text = m_text.Substring(m_Index);
                    else
                        m_text = string.Empty;
                }
```

So, this was the logic that processes a string. Lets see the helper methods that will handle the events:

Press and release special keys are the same, only the first two parameters are different.
Check msdn to get the virtual and scan codes for enter, tab, alt, altgr, etc...

```
#region [ Press shift ]
private void PressShift()
{
    //0xA0 is the virtual key of 'shift'.
    //0x2A is the scan code of 'shift'.
    keybd_event(0xA0, 0x2A, 0, 0);
} 
#endregion

#region [ Release shift ]
private void ReleaseShift()
{
    keybd_event(0xA0, 0x2A, 0x0002, 0);
} 
#endregion
```

PressSpecial is similar to the code above, so it can be used for shift as well. I separated some of them into different methods as for me its easier to see what i use in the code (its easier for me to use 'PressShift();' instead of 'PressSpecial("shift")';). :)

```
private void PressSpecial(string p_Special)
{
    switch (p_Special.ToLower()) //<-- use lower version!
    {
        case "home":
            keybd_event(0x24, 0x47, 0, 0);
            break;
        case "end":
            keybd_event(0x23, 0x4F, 0, 0);
            break;
        //Do the same for any key you need (enter, tab, page up, etc...).
        //Remember to get the proper virtual- and scan codes for each keys!
    }
}
```

ReleaseSpecial is the same as PressSpecial, but the 3rd parameter is 0x0002.

```
private void ReleaseSpecial(string p_Special)
{
    switch (p_Special.ToLower())
    {
        case "home":
            keybd_event(0x24, 0x47, 0x0002, 0);
            break;
        case "end":
            keybd_event(0x23, 0x4F, 0x0002, 0);
            break;
    }
}
```

And finally, here are the dll import methods. You can put them into a static class, if you wish:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "keybd_event", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte vk, byte scan, int flags, int extrainfo);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint idThread);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern short VkKeyScanEx(char ch, IntPtr dwhkl); 

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int MapVirtualKey(int uCode, int uMapType);
```

Comment: i have open RDC using AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting dll and display that remote computer screen  in my form. remote computer shows windows activation dialog at startup. i want to press ESC from my code to remove that dialog on remote computer. can you help?